# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ognl.SimpleNode.isSequence(Lognl/OgnlContext;)Z

Tags: java, struts

I am trying to upgrade my `struts` version from `2.3.3` to `2.3.33`.post running the `apache tomcat 7` I am getting the below error.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ognl.SimpleNode.isSequence(Lognl/OgnlContext;)Z
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.isEvalExpression(OgnlUtil.java:320)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.checkEnableEvalExpression(OgnlUtil.java:431)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:386)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:298)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.internalSetProperty(OgnlUtil.java:627)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setProperties(OgnlUtil.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setProperties(OgnlUtil.java:217)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setProperties(OgnlUtil.java:204)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlReflectionProvider.setProperties(OgnlReflectionProvider.java:58)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:43)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:209)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1114)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:932)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:945)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:968)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:537)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:295)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:264)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:978)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

I am using `ognl-3.0.4` jar

Comment: Anyone having any solution regarding this,then please comment

Answer (score 1):

For googlers, the problem in my case (when I got a similar exception) was a mismatch between `thymeleaf` and `ognl` versions.

The versions I used later that worked fine together:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem has been resolved now,it is the jar issue after upgrading the struts version step by step 2.3.3 to 2.3.15 then 2.3.28 and then 2.3.33, i have not faced this problem.